# A simple Lisp question

Tags: lisp

I now have a problem on using "reduce" to implement my own version of copy-list.
This is what I have done:

```
(defun my-copy-list (lst)  
  (reduce #'(lambda (x y)  
              (cons x y)) 
          lst :initial-value nil :from-end t))
```

However, my teacher said there is no need to use that lambda, I am confused on this.  How may we achieve the same functionality without using that lambda (but must use 'reduce').
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Indent your code with 4 spaces to have it placed in a code block and syntax highlighted.

Comment: Not that the "syntax highlighting" on this site does anything useful for non-C-like languages :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What your teacher means is that you're defining this function

```
(lambda (x y) (cons x y))
```

But there's already a function that exists to do that -- `cons` itself.  So instead of passing your lambda as an argument to `reduce`, you could just pass `cons`.

Answer (score 2):

this is what cons does: it takes two values and pairs them.

this is what  `(lambda (x y) (cons x y))` does: it takes two values and pairs them.